# "Index sitecore_suggested_test_index was not found" on CM 8.2 after changing the default Solr index name

Tags: configuration, content-testing

I am running:

- 8.2 Update 7
- Solr
- xDB and Tracking enabled

The Solr instance is shared across DEV and QA, so I need to prefix the index names for all of the indexes so that they do not conflict. I have done this with patch config files and Azure DevOps pipeline replacement variables per environment that prepend an environment specific value for all indexes. So, the "sitecore_suggested_test_index" index for DEV and QA live side by side on the same Solr instance as "dev_sitecore_suggested_test_index" and "qa_sitecore_suggested_test_index" respectively.

I have patched the following:

`<index type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" patch:source="zIndexes.config" id="82u7_sitecore_suggested_test_index">`

`<setting name="ContentTesting.SuggestedTestIndexName" patch:source="zIndexes.config" value="82u7_sitecore_suggested_test_index"/>`

On my CM+Processing server for each environment, I am seeing the following error:

```
ManagedPoolThread #4 18:09:58 ERROR Error executing schedule item: Rebuild Suggested Tests Index
```

```
Exception: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Exceptions.IndexNotFoundException
Message: Index sitecore_suggested_test_index was not found
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(String name)
```

The value `sitecore_suggested_test_index` by itself without the prefix does not appear anywhere in the showconfig.aspx output.

Where else is the name of this index configured?

Answer (score 1):

The name of this index is also specified in the `master` database separately from configuration files. In order to properly rename this index, you must also update the `Index Name` field on the following item:

`/sitecore/system/Tasks/Commands/Content Testing/Rebuild Suggested Tests Index`